# How to get Jenkins parameters in ANT file

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have created a boolean parameter and checked "This project is parameterized" checkbox.

How do I get the boolean parameter value in ANT file? I need that value to perform conditional checking.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will be the steps ...

Boolean parameter has a "Name" , [`MYBOOL`]

That is exposed as environment variable `MYBOOL`

In your ant script, insert:

`<property environment="env"/>`

and reference as follows in your conditional check:

`${env.MYBOOL}`